# AWS and Django: "Couldn't import Django"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am new programming in Django. I do a local demo and it runs without problem but the next step is deploying the Django application on AWS Elastic beanstalk, I am trying that.

I have this Enviroment: 
~/Python_Env/MiEntorno

And this Project: 
 ~/ProyectosDjango/Refugio

My current Django project structure is this:

```
requirements.txt
.ebextensions
    |-01-django_env.config
.elasticbeanstalk
    |-config.yml
.gitignore
custom_storage.py
manage.py
Refugio
   |__init__.py
   |-settings
   |-urls.py
   |-wsgi.py
|-apps
|-templates
|-static
```

I have this error when i execute this command: **(Mi Entorno) /ProyectosDjango/Refugio> manage.py collectstatic** or **manage.py runserver**

> "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on
>   your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a
>   virtual environment?"

I put this in my -01-django_env.config:

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "Refugio.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/Refugio:$PYTHONPATH"
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python"
    WSGIPath: "Refugio/Refugio/wsgi.py"
```

and in setting I edit the database and add this:

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 's3.refugioprueba.com'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'yy/xxx/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME 
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False 

from boto.s3.connection import ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat 
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = ProtocolIndependentOrdinaryCallingFormat
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection 
S3Connection.DefaultHost = 's3.us.west-1.amazonaws.com'

STATIC_URL = "http://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION) 
MEDIA_URL = "http://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION ) 


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Refugio.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ebdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXX',
        'HOST': 'XXXrds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': 3306, 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's installed in the environment? As in `pip install django` (or whichever specific version you are using)? Or alternatively `pip install -r requirements.txt` if it's in your `requirements.txt` file?
EBS usually automatically installs `requirements.txt` dependencies so placing it there is the safest